# How to set active profiles in Spring annotation based java config

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-4

set active profile like  `context.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles( "DEV" );` 
   which can be achieved by using

```
public class SpringWebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer
{

    public void onStartup( final ServletContext servletContext ) throws ServletException
    {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("DEV" )

    }
}
```

But when extending AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer . 
how can we achieve setting active profile ?

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer
{
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { WebConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Activate your profile by using `spring.profiles.active` property.

```
public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { WebConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
        servletContext.setInitParameter("spring.profiles.active", "DEV");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options..

1. You can try having a context initializer to load the spring profile from a properties file on the classpath, like the following:

   ```
   public class ContextProfileInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

       private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ContextProfileInitializer.class);

       private static final String DEFAULT_SPRING_PROFILE = "local";

       @Override
       public void initialize(final ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {

           ConfigurableEnvironment environment = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
           try {
                   environment.getPropertySources().addFirst(new ResourcePropertySource("classpath:conf/application.properties"));
                   if (environment.getProperty("spring.profiles.active") == null) {
                       environment.setActiveProfiles(DEFAULT_SPRING_PROFILE);
                   }
                   LOGGER.info("Activated Spring Profile: " + environment.getProperty("spring.profiles.active"));
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   LOGGER.error("Could not find properties file in classpath.");
               }
      }

   }
   ```

Here are some guides with more info:

https://gist.github.com/rponte/3989915

http://www.java-allandsundry.com/2014/09/spring-webapplicationinitializer-and.html

2. Alternatively (and a much easier way!) Use Spring Boot.

   You can simply define `spring.profiles.active` in an `application.properties` file in the classpath.  This will automatically be picked up and loaded into your environment.

More info here:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@ActiveProfiles("DEV")` on some of your `@Configuration` classes, but probably more useful would be passing profile from outside - just run your `.jar` with additional parameter like `-Dspring.active.profiles=DEV`

Comment: thanks for the reply @ActiveProfiles("DEV") is in test cases.is there any other better way  the java config.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be rather: -Dspring.profiles.active=...  (Spring 4.1.5)